# Apply zoom level condition for Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a map here:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.0902, longitude: -95.7129, zoom: 4.0)

        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        view = mapView
        mapView.setMinZoom(4.6, maxZoom: 8)
```

I want to detect the zoom level of the user. If zoom level is more than 5, then add marker. How can it be done?

here is the code for adding marker:

```
let state_marker = GMSMarker()
            state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -152.404419, longitude: 61.370716)
            state_marker.title = "Test"
            state_marker.snippet = "Hey, this is Test"
            state_marker.map = mapView
```

Comment: Have you tried camera.zoom?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't give me real time.

Comment: if(camera.zoom > 5) then marker code, this doesn't add marker EVEN after I zoom on the map.

Comment: Try this 
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition*)position {
   float zoom = mapView.camera.zoom;
   // handle you zoom related logic
}

Comment: Sorry the code I gave is objective C

Comment: I didn't understand on how I can write this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124708/discussion-between-dang-and-arun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `didChangeCameraPosition` delegate method of `GMSMapView`

First, you need to extend your `GMSMapView` delegate in your class

```
class MyViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate
```

Then you need to assign your delegate after declaring the mapView

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.0902, longitude: -95.7129, zoom: 4.0)

let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
mapView.delegate = self
view = mapView
mapView.setMinZoom(4.6, maxZoom: 8)
```

You can then use the `didChangeCameraPosition` delegate method

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) { 
    if(mapView.camera.zoom > 5)
      //do your code here
    }
}
```

You can refer the following link to get a better idea on delegate methods of `GMSMapView`
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p